# Show that $\lim_{s\rightarrow \infty} e^s m\left( f^{-1}\left([s,\infty)\right) \right) =0$.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> **Problem**  Suppose that $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be a Lebesgue measurable function such that $$\int_{0}^{1} e^{[f(x)]}dx <\infty.  $$ Show that $$\lim_{s\rightarrow \infty} e^s m\left( f^{-1}\left([s,\infty)\right)  \right) =0$$

**My attempt:**  According to the given condition, it seems I need to put $f(x)$ into $s$, exponent of $e$. But,, I lost my way.

$$e^s m\left( f^{-1}\left([s,\infty)\right)  \right)=e^s \int_{0}^{1} \chi_{[s,\infty)}\circ f(x) dx \\=\int_{0}^{1} e^s \chi_{[s,\infty)}(f(x))dx.......  $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$g_s(x) = e^{s}\cdot \chi_{\{x:f(x)>s\}}.$$ for $s\in \mathbb N$. Note that $g_s(x)\to 0$ almost everywhere, and $|g_s(x)|\le e^{f(x)}\in L_1[0,1]$. By the DCT, $$\lim_{s\to\infty}\int_0^1 g_s(s)\,dx=\lim_{s\rightarrow \infty }e^s\cdot m(\{x:f(x)>s)\})=0$$
Technically, this only proves the limit holds as $s\to \infty$ through the natural numbers. To extend this to $s\to\infty$ through the reals, let $s(n)$ be any sequence converging to $\infty$, and apply the same logic to $g_{s(n)}(x)$. Assuming the axiom of dependent choice, the limit existing through all subsequences implies it exists in general.

Comment: Thanks for answer.:)  But how do you know that $$g_s(x)\rightarrow 0 ?$$ Can't $e^s$ be increasing faster than the decreasing rate of $\chi_{\{ x: f(x)\geq s\}}$?

Comment: Whenever $s>f(x)$, $\chi_{\{x:f(x)>s\}}(x)=0$. So for all $x$, and for large enough $s$, $g_s(x)=0$. The fast growth of $e^s$ cannot compete with being multiplied by $0$! (I do not mean $0$ factorial, I mean $0$ with emphasis :) ) @LevBan

Comment: I got it! :)   Then could I ask why $$\lim_{s\rightarrow \infty}  e^s m\left( \{ x: f(x)\geq s  \}    \right)\rightarrow 0 ? $$  $f(x)$ is point wisely bounded so it seems right... but it is not clear to me :(

Comment: In addition, where did we use the given condition $$ \int_{0}^{1} e^{[f(x)]}dx<\infty ?  $$

Comment: @LevBan You need to review the DCT (Dominated Convergence Theorem).

Comment: Oh! I am sorry!  I was stupid! :( Thank you! Everything got clear !

Comment: @LevBan To be fair, I had a typo and wrote $e^{f(x)}\in L_1(s)$ instead of $L_1[0,1]$, so I was unclear.